# Magento 2: Adding custom attribute for product

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-attribute

I want to add a product attribute like

https://nwdthemes.com/2018/06/21/magento-2-working-with-arrayserialized-backend-model/

How I can create a product attribute with multiple value in one record?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link. I think it will help you.

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-create-product-attribute-magento-2.html